# Can copy semantics cause a Linux system to crash due to huge syscall buffers?

Tags: unix, linux-kernel, operating-system, system-calls, virtual-memory

Before I start, I'm informing you guys that this question is about a hypothetical situation and not one that I would think will happen regularly on modern desktops, and I cannot find a similar question anywhere.
So here's the situation:
Suppose that we have a bare-bones Linux OS desktop computer which has 2GiBs of physical memory, swapping is disabled, zram/memory compression is also disabled, and we have at least one user-level process/thread-group with two threads(The owner of the process is not root). If thread 1 of that process makes a blocking "write()" system call, feeds it a buffer of size 1.5 GiBs, and immediately after making that call, thread 2 goes and changes every single byte of the buffer that thread one fed to the system call. This write system call is related to a slow storage drive; so in our scenario, the kernel won't have enough time to finish the write call before thread two starts wiping data. The main question is: Will this system call finish successfully? or will it lead to a failure of some sort including crashing? Technically, our buffer is smaller than both the amount of physical memory that we have and the maximum size of buffer that we can feed to the "write()" syscall, but apparently there's more to the story.

According to the book "Operating system concepts" aka the dinosaur OS book, the Linux kernel's syscall subsystem supports copy semantics (i.e. copying the user-level buffer into a buffer in the kernel's address space, so that any further changes to that so-called user-level buffer after the syscall is made, will not affect the data that the syscall is going to use. Furthermore, because thread 2 will immediately start writing and changing the data stored in the user-level buffer, the virtual memory cannot use copy-on-write to save physical memory space, forcing the OS to have 2 separate physical memory areas. The problem is, we have a total of 2GiBs of physical memory. But the cumulative size of the kernel buffer and the user-level buffer will exceed 3GiBs which is much more than we have available physically. We cannot benefit from demand paging since swapping is disabled. And even if zram/memory compression was enabled, it would probably not be enough to fit everything in physical memory. so at this point, what would happen? would the infamous OOM killer start killing all user-space tasks and services? What if that wasn't enough either? would it affect kernel's address space size and lead the system to crashing? would we see a deadlock without crashing?

Comment: There is no extra memory usage due to thread 2 modifying the buffer contents (unless thread 2 is modifying copy-on-write pages, such as zeroed pages, but thread 1 will see those modifications too). If thread 2 is modifying the buffer contents during thread 1's `write()` syscall on the same memory, what gets written to the file will be  some mixture of the original and modified contents.

Comment: @IanAbbott You're almost right. Having looked into the source code for the `write()` syscall, I can't see anywhere in which the Linux kernel uses the `copy_from_user()` function. Instead, the user buffer is passed to the `write()` function that the `driver` provides. So in my case, it'd be the SCSI/SATA driver. Nothing is stopping that driver from copying that user buffer into the kernel space to make sure copy semantics is taken care of. But AFAIK, it seems like almost all hardware drivers/kernel modules for storage devices that are included in the kernel, don't implement copy semantics.